# Linux Mint - Not detecting monitor connected via USB-C to HDMI hub

Tags: linux, usb, multi-monitor, hdmi

I recently bought a laptop (Asus Zenbook Flip) and installed Linux Mint. Now I want to connect two external monitors. Connecting the first through the HDMI port works without problems, but for the second one, I bought a hub that supposedly works with Linux (CableMatters USB-C to HDMI).

Connecting ethernet through the hub works flawlessly, but I tried connecting a monitor with a HDMI cable (and I tried another one with a VGA cable). They are not recognized as monitors; in my display settings using “detect displays”, they are not there.

Does anyone know a solution to this, is there anything I can try to make it work?

Comment: I have a similar issue.  I installed Linux Mint on my Acer CB515-1HT (Chromebook) and it does not support external monitors via USB-C.  However, ChromeOS and GalliumOS both support them fine.  I have also found that Ubuntu also does not support them.  So, I continue to investigate.

Comment: Both my monitors are plugged into discrete graphic processor unit. No solution found, only a workaround being to switch between virtual terminals until it powers on

`$ while true; do printf '%b' "Changing VT..."; sudo chvt $(($RANDOM % 64)); read; printf '%b' "Changing VT..."; sudo chvt 2; read; done`

Answer (score 5):

Try opening a console and typing the following:

```
xrandr --auto
```

Make sure that you're providing electricity to the hub with your cable - it should be connected to the laptop's power cable.

Not all USB-C ports support video output, and display output from USB-C might use a standard called "DisplayPort Alt Mode", and that being a standard means that any system that supports video output over USB-C will work with any adapter like this.