# External displays not detected when connected through USB-C hub

Tags: usb, display, multi-monitor, hdmi

I normally work with an external monitor connected by HDMI to a USB-C adapter. I also have a USB-C hub (Aukey CB-C48), tested working with another USB-C device.

The monitor works fine when connected directly to the computer by USB-C. But it is not detected when it is connected through the hub. `udevadm monitor --environment --udev` doesn't show an "add" event, and debug dmesg doesn't show anything responding to a hotplug event either. I tried an older VGA monitor through a different, VGA-to-USBC adaptor as well - same problem.

Is this a known limitation of USB-C hubs in general? Maybe the kernel's implementation? Or is there something I should look for when buying my next hub, to make this possible?

Here's a [dmesg dump](https://gist.github.com/ohthehugemanatee/e2e709c85e1cc499f1bc906a045c54fc) with `drm.debug=0xe`, where I:

1. boot the machine (warm)
2. plug in the hub
3. plug in the monitor
4. unplug the monitor
5. attach a Pixel phone through the hub's powered port
6. move the phone to one of the hub's unpowered ports.

This is probably related to (unanswered) [Linux Mint - Not detecting monitor connected via USB-C to HDMI hub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355772/linux-mint-not-detecting-monitor-connected-via-usb-c-to-hdmi-hub) . I can't seem to find any other resources, though.