# Type C to HDMI not working on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Tags: usb, display, hdmi

Has anyone found a solution to this issue? I've recently installed Linux Mint alongside Windows on a Lenovo T480 and while the Type C port works with an adapter to HDMI when using Windows, Linux Mint does not recognize that the laptop is hooked up to an external display when using a Type C to HDMI adapter.

I've checked this question, but the answer there didn't work: 
[Linux Mint - Not detecting monitor connected via USB-C to HDMI hub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355772/linux-mint-not-detecting-monitor-connected-via-usb-c-to-hdmi-hub?newreg=b1f57b3e5b6f445e8799a182a66bf3fa)

Some help would be appreciated - while I have an HDMI port on the laptop, I would like the option to use my Type C port to hook up another display when using Mint, as well.

Comment: Can you add to the question the model of the adapter? And the output of `lsusb` would also help.